# I have two horizontal scroll views. How can I show one at a time and switch between them on button click?

Tags: java, android, visibility, horizontal-scrolling

On my android app I have two horizontal scroll views that act as docks. How can I make it so that if button 1 is clicked dock 1 displays and if button 2 is clicked dock 2 displays? Since they're docks I want them to both display in the same position.

here is my code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button5" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button5" />
    </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dockButton1" />

               <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dockButton2" />
```

Button code:

```
dock1button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

   }
});

dock2button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:
add id in both of the HorizontalScrollView
for example: `android:id="@+id/hScrollView1"` and `android:id="@+id/hScrollView2"`

Step 2:
Put both HorizontalScrollView in a parent LinearLayout like below:

```
    <LinearLayout>
    <HorizontalScrollView
     android:id="@+id/hScrollView1">
    .
    .         
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <HorizontalScrollView
     android:id="@+id/hScrollView2">
    .
    .
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Step 3:
In your button click just toggle the visibility:
in onClick just use..

```
hScrlView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
hScrlView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and

```
hScrlView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
hScrlView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

where hScrlView1 and hScrlView2 are the ScrollView you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

put the two horizontal listviews in a relative layout and set the visibility of one of them to invisible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>


        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dockButton1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dockButton2" />
```

then change the visibility in buttons' codes:

Button code:

```
dock1button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
     horizontalList2.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
     horizontalList1.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
  }
});

dock2button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) { 
    horizontalList1.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
    horizontalList2.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off by just using `FrameLayout` containing both scrollviews. It would be more performant than using `LinearLayout` or even worse `RelativeLayout`.

Just do something like this (schematic code, some xml attrs omitted)

```
<FrameLayout>
  <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/view1"/>

  <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:visibility="gone"
  />
</FrameLayout>
```

And then in your onClick handler(s) do something like

```
view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
view2.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

or vice versa (depending on button pressed)

Comment: I get cannot resolve symbol error on view1 and view2

Comment: @user1353517 hey, do not expect my to do all the work for you, are you learning Android or copy-pasting code? :) You would need to extract those views from xml, by doing something like **view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1)** in your activity's onCreate(). This is such basic stuff, I didn't mention it. You should figure it out without any problems.